# Use a UUID for an entry ID in a URL path

Tags: craft3, entries

When setting an "Entry URI Format" for a section, the values currently available to me are `{slug}` which is the title of the entry, or `{id}` which is usually a small number. I'd like to have an obfuscated hash/uuid for this path, eg `c54be165-fc95-4583-bef8-2e2abd2a4f37`. Is this possible without writing any custom code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `{uid}` inside the "Entry URI Format" field.

Comment: Ha. That's comically obvious. Thanks.